# solving matrix congruence equation, $A = P B P^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have two $n\times n $ symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, $A=A^T$ and $B = B^T$. Suppose we want to check whether they are congruent to each other. That is, we want to solve $P $ for

$$ A = P B P^T . $$

Here $P^T $ is the transpose of $P $. What is the general method to solve such problems? I know the Sylvester's law of inertia. But here $A$ and $B$ might be complex. If $A$ and $B$ are real, is there always real solution of $P$?

A concrete case is $A= \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right) $, $B= \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right) $. I can find a solution $P = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 1 \\
    i & -i \\
  \end{array}
\right)$. But is there any extra solution?

Comment: There's a real solution if and only if they have the same inertia. If $P$ can be complex, then the solution exists if and only if $A,B$ have the same rank

Comment: Have you considered eigen decomposition?

Answer (score 2):

Since the complex field is quadratically closed, two complex symmetric matrices are T-congruent over $\mathbb C$ if and only if they have the same ranks.

When $A$ and $B$ are T-congruent, there can be infinitely many invertible matrices $P$ such that $A=PBP^T$. In your example, since $A$ is the identity matrix, we have $A=Q^TAQ$ for every orthogonal matrix $Q$. It follows that $A=QPBP^TQ^T$, i.e. $X=QP$ is also a solution to $A=XBX^T$.

Note that T-congruence over $\mathbb C$ does not imply T-congruence over $\mathbb R$. (The $A$ and $B$ in your example already illustrates this: they aren't $T$-congruent over $\mathbb R$ because they have different inertia.) So, even if two real symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ are T-congruent over $\mathbb C$, there does not necessarily exist a real invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=P^TBP$.